# Not able to get the value of Radio Button

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input type="radio" name="animal" id="cat" value="Cat" />
                <label for="cat">Cat</label>

            <input type="radio" name="animal" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2"/>
            <label for="radio-choice-2">Dog</label>

            <input type="radio" name="animal" id="radio-choice-3" value="choice-3"  />
            <label for="radio-choice-3">Hamster</label>

            <input type="radio" name="animal" id="radio-choice-4" value="choice-4"  />
            <label for="radio-choice-4">Lizard</label>
            <input type="button" value="Get Radio Button Value" onclick="getValue();"
```

I want to get the value of selected Radio Button on click of button I had written the code

```
function getValue () {
    alert("Value is :"+$('input[name=animal]:checked').val());  
    }
```

But its not working and getting Undefined

**Update:**

I have used js of Jquery and jquerymobile 
for jquery its for fine but as i am using it for mobile app so i need both  the js library so in second case it didnot work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
```

### **[Solved]**

Comment: Hiya **working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/BJnvt/


Cannot see any issues in jsfiddle please see again bruv! have a good one

Comment: Works for me, the problem is elsewhere in your code: http://jsbin.com/onaded Try to create a minimal, self-contained example demonstrating the problem, and people will be happy to help.

Comment: the code is fine, but you need to make sure that one of the radio buttons is checked.

Comment: T.J. Crowder you did well... great work..

Comment: Thanks Tats_innit...ya its work in your editsheet.but let you know that I am using JQueryMobile so when i import the js of JQM it didnot work....<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: @SumitTiwari: The fact you're using jQuery Mobile was highly relevant and should have been in your question originally (I see you've added it; good!). But it still works for me, provided you do pick a radio button: http://jsbin.com/awekup

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think you are getting the value without checking any radio button.
Load your page then select any one of radio button and then call getValue function

Alternatively you can put any radio button selected by default.

e.g.

replace first radio button with

```
<input type="radio" name="animal" id="cat" value="Cat" checked="true"/>
                <label for="cat">Cat</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have edited my code accordingly but first time it gives the first checked value ie cat but next when i select other radio button ,I am not able to retrieve the selected value.Plz help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this
$("#myform input[type='radio']:checked").val();

OR

var myRadio = $('input[name=myRadio]');

***//Use the filter() function, not find(). (find() is for locating child elements, whereas //filter() searches top-level elements in your selection.)***

var checkedValue = myRadio.filter(':checked').val();

Comment: Its not able to select the radio button.